# while running in Command promt, Error occurs, could not find or load main class DbCheck

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I set path for postgresql driver already. But dont know why this error occurs
Help me to solve the problem

```
 import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class DbCheck {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            try {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres","*","*");
                Statement st=con.createStatement();
                System.out.println("Name: ");
                String name = scan.nextLine();
                String sql= "select * from memberdata where name='" + name +"'";
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                if(rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println("Success");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Failure");
                }
                scan.close();
                con.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Error: could not find or load main class DbCheck

Comment: works for me...

Comment: is it while compiling or while running?

Comment: works in command promt?

Comment: @MauricePerry running

Comment: Please describe how exactly you are starting the program.

Answer (score 0):

Error: could not find or load main class DbCheck

This is not related to postgres driver, you might be trying to run program on different location. Please check your **path where you have compiled program and .class file**. Run class at same location you will get output.

Comment: class file and java file both are in the same directory

Comment: ok so are you running same in that directory?

Comment: yes....! while running the program in cmd, it throws error as could not find main class

Comment: @SelvaKumar is that directory in the classpath? (I bet it isn't)

Comment: i corrected it. i forgot to add .; at the end of  variable path